# How to power 5V MCU from 9V power supply

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I'd like to drive some components (via transistor where necessary) which require a 9V supply from the output of a MCU which operates at 5V (typical).  This works fine by means of a 7805 regulator, but I'm wondering if I can simply use a resistor voltage divider to provide the 5V to the MCU and, if so, are there any additional resistances internal to the MCU that have to be taken into account to correctly configure the voltage divider.  And are ther any other important considerations in such a setup?  Take for example the Microchip PIC16F1823.

Comment: `use a resistor voltage divider to provide the 5V to the MCU` ... only if you do not run any code ... current requirement changes during normal operation, which affects the voltage dropped by the resistor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you could.

If you made a divider that used at least 10 times the maximum current the MCU would use it should stay within around 5% of 5 V, but you would waste an awful lot of power as heat and if you were running off of batteries they probably wouldn't last very long.

As an example, suppose the MCU draws somewhere between microamps and 150 mA, and you wanted to keep the supply voltage within the old TTL range of 4.75 V to 5.25 V (5 V \$\pm\$ 5%), here's a divider that would do it, but as you can see there's over 7 W drawn from the supply where a linear regulator would only waste less than 1/10th of that ((9 V - 5 V)\$\times\$150mA = 0.6 W).

[image: divider as regulator]

Use a regulator, that's what they're for. They're cheap and plentiful. If you know the maximum current your MCU needs you can pick a regulator that suits it, for example while a 7805 is usually rated at 1 A or 1.5 A there are also 78M05 500 mA and 78L05 100 mA versions.

Comment: A 7805 used for 1 A out of a 9 V supply generates 4 W of heat and might need a heat sink to get not too hot.

Comment: Thank you ... from your answer I was able to find the correct rating in the datasheet (which is actually 150mA), therefore your calculation of 0.6W is exactly what I needed and I have ordered some 78M05.  :)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, because the current drawn by an MCU will vary depending on what it's doing, but your resistors won't.  As the current goes up and down, so will the output voltage of your voltage divider.

*When designing voltage dividers, you need to consider the effect of the load on the voltage that will be produced.*

A 7805 is effectively a self-adjusting resistor that keeps its output voltage connstant even if the load current varies.